# Позволить посетителям сайта добавлять поля в форму при создании новой страницы

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо реализовать следующее: Любой посетитель сайта может добавить новую страницу на сайт (подобие wiki). При этом, когда он создаёт новую страницу, редактор должен состоять лишь из кнопок: добавить поле с изображением, добавить поле с текстом, добавить поле с ссылками и т.п..

Как разрешить пользователям добавлять страницы на сайт я разобрался я нашел нужный плагин. Но с редактором проблема. В плагин нет возможности добивать скрипт. Пробовал так же добавить скрипт добавления полей различными другими способами, но нужный скрипт так и не заработал, хотя если запускать его просто через index.html на компе, то все работает.

Подскажите, как можно реализовать подобное? Позволить посетителям добавлять поля в форму через скрипт.

Comment: Будте более конкретны - какой плагин? Добавте в вопрос фрагменты проблемного кода.

Comment: Какие "поля" (что это? какой функционал и тп)? Непременно в редактор?

Answer (score 1):

Плагин WP-Recall позволяет строить разнообразные формы публикаций.
Вроде все что вы описали - у него можно вывести, в админке отключив ненужное
Тут [видеообзор](https://codeseller.ru/post-group/videoobzor-novyx-vozmozhnostej-formy-publikacii-ot-wp-recall/)